# Proper way to use hiera with puppetlabs-spec-helper?

Tags: puppet

I am trying to write some rspec tests for my modules. Most of them now use hiera.

I have a .fixures.yml:

```
fixtures:
  repositories:
    stdlib: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib.git
    hiera-puppet: https://github.com/puppetlabs/hiera-puppet.git
  symlinks:
    mongodb: "#{source_dir}"
```

and a spec/classes/mongodb_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'mongodb', :type => 'class' do

  context "On an Ubuntu install, admin and single user" do
    let :facts do
      {
        :osfamily => 'Debian',
        :operatingsystem => 'Ubuntu',
        :operatingsystemrelease => '12.04'
      }
    end

    it {
      should contain_user('XXXX').with( { 'uid' => '***' } )
      should contain_group('XXXX').with( { 'gid' => '***' } )
      should contain_package('mongodb').with( { 'name' => 'mongodb' } )
      should contain_service('mongodb').with( { 'name' => 'mongodb' } )
    }
  end
end
```

but when I run the spec test, I get:

```
# rake spec
/usr/bin/ruby1.8 -S rspec spec/classes/mongodb_spec.rb --color
F

Failures:

  1) mongodb On an Ubuntu install, admin and single user
     Failure/Error: should contain_user('XXXX').with( { 'uid' => '***' } )
     LoadError:
       no such file to load -- hiera_puppet
     # ./spec/fixtures/modules/hiera-puppet/lib/puppet/parser/functions/hiera.rb:3:in `function_hiera'
     # ./spec/classes/mongodb_spec.rb:15

Finished in 0.05415 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/classes/mongodb_spec.rb:14 # mongodb On an Ubuntu install, admin and single user
rake aborted!
/usr/bin/ruby1.8 -S rspec spec/classes/mongodb_spec.rb --color failed

Tasks: TOP => spec_standalone
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Module spec testing is relatively new, as is hiera. So far I have been unable to find any suitable solutions. (the back and forth on puppet-dev was interesting, but not helpful).

What changes do I need to make to get this to work? Installing puppet from a gem and hacking on rubylib isn't a viable solution due to corporate policy.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS + Puppet 2.7.17 + hiera 0.3.0.

Comment: In case anyone else finds this, have a look at this sample repo for a way to mock the hiera function, if that's what you're looking for! https://github.com/TomPoulton/rspec-puppet-unit-testing#mocking-hiera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Officially, hiera is not supported for puppetlabs_spec_helper with 2.7, and will be available in a future, 3.x compatible release.

Unofficially, the [Puppet Developers mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/puppet-dev/x6BXXkxd0nE/discussion) told me  there is a "hackish" [patch](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs_spec_helper/pull/15) you can apply to puppetlabs_spec_helper that will allow spec tests to be written with hiera support. The downside is, it's likely to break / require some rewrites and such when 3.0 finally comes out.

Answer (score 2):

### The rspec-hiera-puppet gem

https://github.com/amfranz/rspec-hiera-puppet

In your Gemfile:

```
gem 'puppet'

gem 'rspec-puppet'
gem 'rspec-hiera-puppet'
gem 'puppetlabs_spec_helper'

gem 'hiera'
gem 'hiera-puppet'
```

In your `spec_helper.rb`: `require 'rspec-hiera-puppet'

In `spec/shared_context.rb`:

```
require 'rspec-hiera-puppet'

shared_context "hieradata" do
  let :hiera_config do
    {
     # this specifies that rspec overrides what's been defined in `riak::params`
     :backends => ['rspec', 'puppet'],
     :hierarchy => ['%{location}', '%{environment}', '%{calling_module}'],
     :puppet   => { :datasource => 'params' },
     :rspec    => respond_to?(:hiera_data) ? send(:hiera_data) : {}
    }   
  end 
end
```

I'm using it here:

https://github.com/haf/puppet-riak

Feel free to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `puppetlabs_spec_helper` doesn't support hiera at the moment. I'm hopeful there will be a good solution either from somebody in Puppet or somebody in the community sooner than later. I know lots of people use Hiera, and I really want them to be able to use the tools we have for testing modules.

Comment: I have found a potential workaround from the puppet-users mailing list. I will give an update once I have had a chance to test it, but it looks promising.

Comment: the workaround did not work. However, since this is something provided by puppetlabs, and puppet 3 will have hiera tightly integrated into it, I have a hard time believing it can't be done. I suspect it is a configuration issue, but I don't know for sure.